# Laravel Homestead Upgrading Node.js

Tags: node.js, laravel-5.1

I am new to Laravel but just installed a fresh installation of Laravel 5.1 on Homestead/Vagrant according to the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/homestead).

When I do npm install, I get this warning:

```
vagrant@homestead:~/Code/Laravel$ sudo npm install
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@0.3.8
npm WARN engine get-stdin@5.0.0: wanted: {"node":">=0.12.0"} (current: {"node":"0.10.37","npm":"1.4.28"})
```

Is it safe to upgrade node.js and if yes, how?
I read some articles where people destroyed their vagrant installation so I am afraid to do that. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node js > 0.12.0 is very supported, since it is around since a long time. you can upgrade.

But why do you do npm install in laravel, isn't it a PHP framework? In the install procedure in their website they don't mention npm, maybe I'm wrong.

EDIT: To manage node.js versions you can use `nvm` https://github.com/creationix/nvm
This allows you to switch between versions easily, and install any version available without any issue. You can even set different versions for different paths.

Comment: ok thanks. I tried to install bower and gulp via npm (actually according to this docs http://www.codeheaps.com/php-programming/creating-website-using-laravel-5-elixir-assets/). Is there any recommend way on how to upgrade?

Comment: It all depends on how you install node. Most people today use `nvm`. https://github.com/creationix/nvm you can switch between many versions, and even se a version for ust a certain folder.

Comment: ok I just upgraded node js with sudo n 0.12.7 and I had to do hash -r. Now it seems to work. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Look at:

https://nodesource.com/blog/nodejs-v012-iojs-and-the-nodesource-linux-repositories#the-nodesource-linux-repositories

---

Installing Node.js v0.12 Debian / Ubuntu repository

## Note the new setup script name for Node.js v0.12

curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_0.12 | sudo bash -

## Then install with:

sudo apt-get install -y nodejs